# Vertically center text box in MsAccess 365

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to vertically center a text box in MSAccess 365.  In the format menu it only shows Horizontal center/top/bottom.

I've searched the web and didn't find any results that would work.  Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an event handler to the `On Resize` event of your Form:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Resize()
    myTextBox.Top = (Me.InsideHeight - myTextBox.Height) / 2
    myTextBoxLabel.Top = myTextBox.Top 'Just in case you have a label too
End Sub
```